# How to see every dependency in a Python program (e.g. imports)?

Tags: python-3.x, dependencies

I have several apps I'm developing that are for end users that have no idea how to use Python.  I have already discovered how to setup a package that allows them to run any script without Python knowledge but I don't know how to minimize the distribution size by only including subsets (I.e. the actual function calls in large libs like NumPy) of each imported library that are required.  Is there a way to output the actual subcomponents of each imported library that are actually accessed during the function?  All my internet searches end up with cyclical imports which is not what I need.  There must be some Python dependency walker equivalent I have yet to discover.  Much appreciated any libs that can outline this.

[UPDATE]
I converted Snakefood 1.4 over to Python 3x (3.5 tested to build) with `python setup.py install` and saved it here: https://github.com/mrslezak/snakefood per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/doc/snakefood-doc.html)

Here's a command

```
sfood -i -r myscript.py | sfood-cluster > dependencies.txt
```